# Why Class.forName thowing a ClassNotFoundException even though I'm specifically importing that exact class?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
Class<?> classType = Class.forName(typeClassName);
```

It keeps throwing an error everytime I try to run the code:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: EmailAddress
```

But I'm speciaifially importing the EmailAddress class into the class that I'm running the first code:

```
import ie.folder.EmailAddress;
```

How can this be?

Comment: You need to use the full name of the class. `Class.forName("ie.folder.EmailAddress");` - why you want to do that is currently a mystery.

Comment: If you're already importing it, why are you using `forName`? (Note that in neither case does this guarantee that the class is on your classpath *at runtime*; the import simply guarantees that you'll get a compiler error if it's not there at build time.)

Comment: Instead of dynamically loading the class with `forName`, do this: `Class<?> classType = EmailAddress.class;`

Comment: If the class `EmailAddress` is not in a package, try to put it a package so the compiler will not be confuse in importing the class. That would be the workaround I think will work

Comment: "typeClassName" could be one of around 15 different classes. I was just using EmailAddress as an example

Answer (score 1):

If you are already importing the class there is no need to use reflection, you can just do

```
Class<EmailAddress> clazz = EmailAddress.class;
```

You would only really need to use `Class.forName` if you do not know the class name at the time you compile your program. If you still want to do that, you need to use the fully qualified class name (the imports do not matter, they are not considered at runtime, only during compilation).

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("ie.folder.EmailAddress");
```

And you have to deal with the exception if that class could not be found or loaded.

Comment: "typeClassName" could be one of around 15 different classes. I was just using EmailAddress as an example